# Outlook add-in redirecting to unwanted URLs

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, outlook-addin

I'm trying to call `https://my-office-site.com/TokenAddin`, which is where the Java servlet I need is located, inside an Outlook add-in, and I have no idea why it keeps redirecting me to other URLs. I'm using `XMLHttpRequest` to make the calls.

If I call the site from a browser it works as it should: it redirects to an Office login URL, automatically logs in, as I'm logged in already on the browser, and comes back to `https://my-office-site.com/TokenAddin`.

If I call it from the add-in though, it redirects to `https://my-office-site.com/index.jsp?path=%2Fnubbius%2FTokenAddin` and gets blocked by CORS policy, which is very weird to me because:

- I have added the header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'` to every servlet in my company and to `https://my-office-site.com/index.jsp`, and whenever I call them directly from the browser I can see that those headers are effectively there.
- If I call `https://my-office-site.com/index.jsp?path=%2Fnubbius%2FTokenAddin` directly from the browser it just sends me back to what I wanted in the first place, `https://my-office-site.com/TokenAddin`.

I've then tried to call instead `https://my-office-site.com/index.jsp?path=%2Fnubbius%2FTokenAddin` inside the add-in, but it redirects to this monster: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=8613bd0c-93a9-46a3-a697-dd9ce9358f4f&client_secret=7lthp5nTenUOOW4uug4iEfe2x%2Fpxh8LwTZ%2FcSwPX%2F4A%3D&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdodespacho.nubbius.com%2Fnubbius%2FO365OpenIDCallBack&state=2a25c9dc-fff5-4603-a755-3a0c9e92d499&nonce=b724a92a-d50b-4df2-a28e-5079ba858047&response_mode=form_post`, which is obviously blocked again by CORS policy.

What am I doing wrong, or what do I not know? Is there a way to keep the add-in from redirecting to different URLs or to know where it's going to redirect?

Comment: I was preventing it from doing a correct login because I was forcing it to do it on the same tab it was being called (which I so far do not understand, just've been told it works that way. I really hope I end up knowing why!).

This has been helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384018/6380056.

Comment: You need to define url in appDomain tag of manifesto .xml file